# Using Gregorian calendar to compare with current date without external class

Tags: java, calendar

I'm supposed to ask the user for their age, and in return I'm supposed to check how many days they've lived for. I've tried searching here but I couldn't quite get how to do it.

**Condition:** Method that takes a GregorianCalendar date as an argument and returns the number of days difference between that date and today. **I cannot use any external classes for this.**

Here's my unfinished code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int day;
    int month;
    int year;
    int difference;
    Scanner scanIn = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Please enter your birth date.");
    System.out.println("Please enter the month you were born in (mm)");
    month = scanIn.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Please enter the day you were born in (dd)");
    day = scanIn.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Please enter the year you were born in (yyyy)");
    year = scanIn.nextInt();

    GregorianCalendar greg = new GregorianCalendar(year, month, day);

    difference = getDifference(greg);
    month = greg.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 2;
    year = greg.get(Calendar.YEAR);

    //System.out.println("Year is " + year);
    //System.out.println("Month " + month);

}

public static int getDifference(GregorianCalendar greg) {
     Calendar now = new GregorianCalendar();
     int difference;
     System.currentTimeMillis.greg(); 

    difference = greg - now;
    return difference;
}
```

I don't understand how to get the difference?

My instructor advised us to use milliseconds to solve the problem, but I've already spent 4 hours trying to solve this and I don't understand this.

How do I get the current day, month and year?

Comment: Please bother to search Stack Overflow before posting.

Answer (score 2):

It is recommended to use the [new date API](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jf14-date-time-2125367.html) in Java 8 instead of the  `Calendar` API. In particular, you could use the method `ChronoUnits.DAYS.between()` as described [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html). I suggest this:

```
    LocalDate dob = LocalDate.of(year, month, day);
    LocalDate now = LocalDate.now();
    difference=(int)ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(dob, now);

    System.out.println("Days since date of birth: " + difference);
```

You can easily check that is gives the same result than with the old interface:

```
    GregorianCalendar greg = new GregorianCalendar(year, month-1, day);
    Calendar nowCal = new GregorianCalendar();      
    long deltaMillis = nowCal.getTime().getTime() - greg.getTime().getTime();

    System.out.println("Days since date of birth: " + deltaMillis/(1000*60*60*24));
```

Note that the `Calendar` interface starts counting the months from 0, where the new API starts at 1.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Calendar is deprecated? Have a look into Calendar API of Java8 https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html.

Comment: No, you're right, thanks.

Comment: While not formally deprecated, the java.util.Date/.Calendar classes suffer from poor design and are now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes. Explained by Oracle [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jf14-date-time-2125367.html)

Comment: I was surprised it's not formally deprecated. Any idea why? Will it be deprecated in Java 9?

Answer (score 1):

If you can only use GregorianCalendar, one way to do it would be converting both instances of calendar to their millisecond representation through `getTimeInMillis`, subtracting them, then calculate how many days that represents through dividing it by (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000).

For instance:

```
public static int countDaysSince(GregorianCalendar pastDate) {
    GregorianCalendar now = GregorianCalendar.getInstance();

    long difference = pastDate.getTimeInMillis() - now.getTimeInMillis();
    return difference / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000); // 24 hours, 60 minutes, 60 seconds, 1000 milliseconds
}
```

That should do it.